# Is it safe to publish fullchain.pem, privkey.pem and dhparams.pem if only used in a test system?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I want to make running the tests easier. To achieve this I want to provide the secrets used in the tests inside my project.
I create the 'fullchain.pem', 'privkey.pem' and 'dhparams.pem' with this commands:

```
openssl genrsa > privkey.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem > fullchain.pem
```

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 4096
```

Is it safe to publish this files if I run the tests in a local network?

Comment: Why? Just include generation of the secrets in the test suite.

Comment: Portability: I think this commands do not work on windows. //
Maintainability: This commands could change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but after testing you should regenerate these files.

Comment: With publishing I mean add the files to my project which is publicly accessible. I like to know if this is a good idea and if not why.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing the architecture of your system, however, in general if something is bad practice in production, it should be bad practice in development (with the exception of being able to turn on dev tools).

So this is where the architecture of the system comes into play. For a server side system, your PEM should always remain local and only the public key ever leave the server. If you have a need to get the PEM on the client side, there is something fundamentally wrong with your system you need to fix.

Your keys are also only important when they are known. So, if you do something unsafe with them in testing, but create new ones for production, there isn't an issue (assuming you are using dummy data in testing).

As for your question about adding the files once you publish your system, you should be placing the files on your server in a non-publicly available area. Typically you'll have something like a structure like this:

```
 var/www/{publicly available content}
```

you should then be putting your keys somewhere like this:

```
var/.ssh/{private keys}
```

The files on your server can access them, but not the public.

Comment: I will recreate the keys for production. My test system can not be reached from the outside. I want that the developers of my project can clone the project build the tests and run them without wondering about the secrets. I kinda have the feeling that this is a bad practice but I do not know why. Maybe in my case it is fine?

Comment: I guess it's a bad practice because you should never have such keys in your repo and you don't want to get used to having them in your repo or else you might forget and let them free. The best thing to do might be to have a command in your application to programatically create the keys, and then include instructions to run that command while setting it up for local dev.

Answer (score 0):

Attackers can obvious get access to your tests secrets when you make them public. But then, how much of an impact can they make with those secrets? It's hard to say without knowing more about your system and use cases.

Exposing secrets publicly is always considered a bad practice, but it's not always harmful, as the system might also have other security measures. For example, one mights have the secrets to an internal system, but they cannot do anything before they can pass throught the firewall. Another example is when the system is just a toy system without any value to protect, the owner might prioritize simplicity over security.

Back to your specific case, if you think the simplicity is worth and your system does not hold any crucial value/information, you can continue using this way. If not, there are some solutions that I can suggest for the 2 problems that you mentioned in the comments (Portability and Maintainability):

- **If you prefer generating secrets once**: Use a secret management system, there are many choices out there. Personally, I use chezmoi and bitwarden (I then just need to refer the secret in my public git repo, the actual secrets are stored in bitwarden).
- **If you prefer regenerate secrets every time you run the tests (this is the more idiomatic way)**: You should rely on other tools to provide you the Portibility and Maintainability. Traditionally, people would include several static binary and/or script versions for each OS version that they care. A better way these day is to use docker image with sha hash so you can guarantee that it will run anywhere and will never change.